# What is the best way to let a function execute after setState completely changed the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

```
  const [selectedTopic, setSelectedTopic] = React.useState('')

  const [a, setA] = React.useState(articles)
  
  const handleApply = () => {
    setA(articles)
    if (selectedTopic !== "") {
      setA(a.filter((article) => {
        return selectedTopic === article.frontmatter.topic
      }))
    }
  }
```

I am trying to update A, but I don't think it is updating before the filter method is executed because `setState` is asynchronous. What is the best solution for this situation. Many posts told to use `useEffect`, but that wouldn't work in my situation as that will cause an infinite loop. Please tell me if I need to provide more detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the filter method on the `articles` array instead

```js
const handleApply = () => {
  if (selectedTopic !== "") {
    setA(
      articles.filter((article) => {
        return selectedTopic === article.frontmatter.topic;
      })
    );
  } else {
    setA(articles);
  }
}
```